# Performance issue while reading XML File in Java and storing it in Database

Tags: java, xml, performance, hibernate, spring

Hi I have big xml file which has a structure similar to the one I have given below  and there are 1 lakh users in each XML file . I am uploading as a zip file and then I am extracting it . Once Extraction is done I am providing a Import link. what import does is it reads the XML file which has 1lakh(100000) users and then inserts into DB . I am using Spring with hibernate and have quartz job scheduler . I am uploading 10 such files and I am starting these 10 jobs which totally consists of 1 million lakh users.the jobs stops in the middle . I am not sure why the job stops and i see no trace of the job stopping . Please help me in resolving this . Is there a better way to read the XML , or anything to do with hibernate transactions or sessions. Please help.
I am using java,spring, hibernate,quartz job scheduler.

```
<userlist application="1">
<user>
<username> xmluser1 </username>
<userid>1</userid>
<password>xmluser1</password>
<firstname>first1</firstname>
<lastname>last1</lastname>
<phone>2024676868</phone>
<fax>20246868</fax>
<address1><![CDATA[dghggggh]]></address1>
<address2></address2>
<city>ghgdghg</city>
<state>fdghg</state>
<country>UdghgSA</country>
<postal_code>774dghg07</postal_code>
<company>dghggg services</company>
</user>
</userlist>
```

Comment: You probably should include, the error which makes the process stop, if any (check your logs), for how long the processes run? what database are you accessing? are you using a transaction for the whole file or per row?...

Comment: Its per row . I Could not see any error logs but the transaction commit is not happening . I have also changed my log4j properties file so tht it logs only errors and the performance is better.

Comment: At the time the process finishes, is there any data in the database? If not, you are probably only committing at the very end...

Comment: data is present only till the level where it stops . recently i changed my logging level to FATAL and i was able to see that constarint violation exception is being thrown on duplicate entry of same user with same username coz of different threads trying to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest, you are inserting data from 10 different jobs to same table, is any db table locking taking place. You can try lowering isolation level. Which database are you using. May be this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much . I think i should use some kind of db table locking . I am using MySql database. I changed my logging level to FATAL and i was able to see that there is a constraint violation . ie Duplicate Entry error in DB .I am not sure how to do table locking via hibernate.